# SpringBoot named query: IN-clause not working for multiple values

Tags: spring-boot, named-query, in-clause

"In clause" not working on passing multiple values

Repository code

```
@Query( "select myObject from MyObject myObject where myObject.anyColumn in :values" )
public List<MyObject> findPriDestByCntryAbbr(@Param("values") List<String> values);
```

Calling from service

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(valuesString.split(","));
List<MyObject> result = myObjectRepository.findByAnyColumns(values);
```

When i am passing single value it is retrieving correct information from table, But on passing multiple values in List "values" giving empty result

Comment: Did you check the content of the `values` variable  ?

Comment: Yes, I did 'values ' are correct

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should work. You should check the values variable.

The other way you can try is- without writing query.
As per the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) we can create MyObjectRepository interface by extending Repository interface and then have a method to fetch all MyObjects. It goes like:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends Repository<MyObject,**Long**> {

List<MyObject> findBy**AnyColumn**In(Collection<String> values);

}
```

"AnyColumn" is your column name and second parameter for Repository interface is as per your requirement.

Comment: I did exactly above, worked fine for single value on multiple value ['Val1', 'Val2'] giving error as java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis as created query having extra parenthesis for IN clause "Select Col1, Col2 From TableName WHERE (Col1 IN (('Val1', 'Val2')))"

Comment: I think its  due to eclipse-link [Ref-link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/119934-in-clause-not-working-for-jpa-eclipselink-repository-mysql-error)